# Is it possible to have multiple subscriptions in an Azure Logic App that's paired with an Event Grid?

Tags: azure-logic-apps, azure-eventgrid

I have a logic app in Azure Subscription 1. It's paired with an Event Grid which is also in Subscription 1. Is it possible for this logic app to monitor Subscriptions 1, 2 and 3? Or is it designed to not go cross-subscription?

Comment: What kind of Event Grid Events are you monitoring? Azure Subscription Events?

Comment: yes. subscription events.

Answer (score 2):

The Logic App Event Grid Trigger can only connect to one Azure Subscription at a time. You would need to create 3 Logic Apps, each connecting to different Azure Subscriptions. Then each of these can connect to a common (Nested) Logic App that has all the business logic you want to run.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

There is only one Event Grid service in the Azure Subscription. If your event subscriber wants to subscribe an event subscription from multiple Event Grids, the Custom Topic Endpoint and Azure Function can be used for this event source  plumbing, see the following screen snippet:

[image: MultipleEventGrids]

Answer (score 0):

This is actually natively supported with Event Grid & Logic Apps. In the Logic Apps designer, create a new Event Grid Trigger. The first option you configure there is the Subscription which you are interested in. This will allow you to listen to events in any Azure Subscription.

[Logic Apps editor for Event Grid trigger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8JM9i.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can just use an `Http Trigger` Logic App.

You can then configure each subscription to send event to your logic app.