# How to authenticate my Logic App Dynamics F&O connection with API Connection

Tags: api, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-365-operations

I am working on a logic app which needs to get data from Dynamics F&O. I am using Get action for Dynamics F&O but I cannot use Sign in method or Service Principal due to some reason. I rather store my service principal Client ID and Secret in an API Connection which is in my Logic App.

My question is, how should I connect to using that API Connection which has Client ID and secret for my service principal or should I have  to use some other task to achieve this or get data from Dynamics F&O

Comment: did you tried anything. It would be great if you provide more details by adding images to your question.

Comment: Yes, 
1. I created API Connection to F&O after registering App.I have defined API Connection in Logic App.
2. I added, Get record from F&O Task to my Logic App
3. Then LA ask for authentication, I change LA code and put API connection rather then Service Principal or Signin

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API Connection that you created to connect to Dynamics F&O. To authenticate with the API Connection, you can use the `HTTP` action in your Logic App. Here are the steps to do so:

- Refer this azure [active directory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/servicebus/get-azure-active-directory-token) token document to register your logic App with Azure active directory and to get bearer token.
  [image]
  Then in your logic App workflow,

1. Add an `HTTP` action to your Logic App.
2. In the `HTTP` action, set the `Method` to `POST`.
3. Set the `URI` to `https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant-id}/oauth2/token`, where `{tenant-id}` is the ID of your Azure AD tenant.
4. In the `Headers` section, add the following key-value pairs:

- `Content-Type`: `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`
- `Authentication type`:   `Active Directory OAuth`

[image]

- Then in you can connect to Dynamic F&0 get records action  by providing connection name, client id, client secret and tenant details as taken in http action.
  [image]
- As mentioned in this @ [AMREEK SINGH](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/mscrmshop/posts/calling-d365-apis-from-logic-apps) blog after http action you can also use parse Json action.

  In the `Parse JSON` action, set the `Content` to the output of the `HTTP` action. Then you can take Get records action of F&O.
  Refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786863/azure-logic-app-how-to-use-it-beyond-its-subscription) and MS [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-custom-api-authentication?tabs=azure-portal) it may helps.