# Logic app to list the subscriptions under my management group and list them one per row, with tag values as columns

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I'm trying to replace the report I have been running via Powershell with a Logic App, to automate it and store the results in Sharepoint. However, I can't find a way to list the subscription tags and theit values within the logic app, only the tag names or the tag names and values for the resources hosted in the subscription. The main problem is all the tags aren't always present, so it has to be a dynamic list.

I have been trying to use the action "Get tags for each subscription", iterating theough the subscription list as it was the recommended one, but it lists the tags and values for all the nested resources.

I have also been trying to create a Kusta query to list the tags and their valules, but that only brought out the tag names.

Comment: Can you share the PowerShell commands you are trying to replace with Logic Apps?

Comment: # Loop through subscription
foreach ($subscription in $subscriptions) {
    # Select subscription
    Set-AzContext -Subscription $subscription.Id
    # Get tags
    $tags = (Get-AzContext).Subscription.Tags
    # Store subscription, tag values
    $obj = New-Object PSObject
    $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Subscription Name" -Value $subscription.Name
    # Add tags
    foreach ($tag in $tags.GetEnumerator()) {
        $obj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $tag.Key -Value $tag.Value
    }
    # Add object to array
    $output += $obj
}

Comment: I can also get the same information with a Graph query, but I'm not sure how could I execute it inside a logic app:  
`ResourceContainers  
| where type =~ 'microsoft.resources/subscriptions'  
| project  name , tags`

Comment: Thank you for sharing these details. Please see my answer below - a simple HTTP request will return the required data.

Answer (score 0):

You can get subscription name  from `List subscriptions` action and tag value `List subscription resource tags` in logic app using below **`design`**:

[image]

**`Output:`**

[image]

Also refer this [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75786863/azure-logic-app-how-to-use-it-beyond-its-subscription).

Answer (score 0):

In a Logic App, you need to use 2 `HTTP` actions: the first one to get a list of subscriptions, and the second to get the tags from each subscription.

[image]

Your first `GET` request goes to https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01

Response:

[image]

The `For each` action will iterate the array with the subscription details:

[image]

The second [`GET`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/tags/get-at-scope?view=rest-resources-2021-04-01&tabs=HTTP#get-tags-on-a-subscription) request goes to [https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@{item()?['subscriptionId']}/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default?api-version=2021-04-01](https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/@%7Bitem()?%5B%27subscriptionId%27%5D%7D/providers/Microsoft.Resources/tags/default?api-version=2021-04-01) -

[image]

Result:

[image]

**Update**: The other provided answer does the same but with the help of the [`Azure Resource Manager`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/arm/) connector, which might seem to be a better approach if you didn't want to use `HTTP` actions :)